# Primary servers in capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

I have a task in capistrano wherein I want just a single line to run only if the server is a marked as primary.  Is there a variable or method that I can reference inside a task?  'primary?' or 'primary' doesn't seem to work.

I've also tried something akin to the following:

```
after "deploy", "task1"
after "deploy", "task2"
after "deploy", "task3"

task :task1, :roles => :app do
  *code*
end

task :task2, :roles => :app, :only => {:primary => true} do
  *code for just primary server*
end

task :task3, :roles => :app do
  *more code*
end
```

But even this doesn't seem to work (all three tasks get run on every server).

I've been working on this on and off for a few days and I'm having no luck with my searches.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

I've solved the issue, but it wasn't pretty.  The thing that I've found is that you need to use the 'primary => true' on a per-task basis.  Looking at the code, it appears that capistrano generates a list of the servers that the task will be run on before the task is run.